# Using IExternalizable on a custom class with a property that is another custom class and saving/loading - AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, serialization, save, deserialization

I have been experiencing an issue with a class of mine which implements IExternalizable. I have experimented with it and, attempted to save/load an object which contains all of the game's save data.

My "Character.as" class is a custom class which implements IExternalizable.

```
public function writeExternal(output:IDataOutput):void {
        output.writeUTF(_characterName);
        output.writeUTF(_description);
        output.writeDouble(_experience);

        //_level is a custom class called "OffsetNumber"
        var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        ba.writeObject(_level);
        ba.position = 0; //return to start after writing object
        output.writeBytes(ba);
    }
    public function readExternal(input:IDataInput):void {
        _characterName = input.readUTF();
        _description = input.readUTF();     
        _experience = input.readDouble();
        _level = input.readObject();
    }
```

Inside of OffsetNumber() which is another custom class that implements IExternalizable.

```
public function writeExternal(output:IDataOutput):void {
        output.writeDouble(_baseValue);
        output.writeDouble(_offset);
        output.writeBoolean(_offsetIncreased);
        output.writeBoolean(_maximumOffsetReached);
    }
    public function readExternal(input:IDataInput):void {
        _baseValue = input.readDouble();
        _offset = input.readDouble();
        _offsetIncreased = input.readBoolean();
        _maximumOffsetReached = input.readBoolean();
    }
```

In my Main.as script, I register both:

```
registerClassAlias("OffsetNumber", OffsetNumber);
registerClassAlias("Character", Character);
```

And then elsewhere I save an "Object{}" which contains various save data values, including the Character.

```
        dataToSave = {
            'myCharacter':characterInstance,
            'someotherData':'xyz',
            'etc':315
        }
```

The problem comes when trying to load the data back. The returned data comes back weird sometimes, like this:

```
------------myCharacter = [object Character]
------------xyz = etc
```

It's as if values or key/pairs are getting mixed up/missing. What I am trying to explain is that, it seems nested custom classes aren't being saved/restored correctly. I have looked all over the internet and tried various approaches. The only way I can get my save data saving/loading correctly is if I make _level a Number instead of OffsetNumber (removing the custom class from within another custom class).

I hope I have explained the issue well enough.

Comment: I'm not really understanding the problem.  I've saved nested classes before and can attest that it works (though it's been many years now since I've done so in AS3).    What exactly is the data you're saving VS. the data you're getting back?   Is the `myCharacter` value read back the string `"[object Character]"` or an actual `Character` instance?

Comment: I have a feeling it's because I save an OffsetNumber as well as Character, which also contains a nested OffsetNumber. I cant think of what else could be the issue here. Unless I have an unrelated bug that is getting resolved by setting _level to Number instead of OffsetNumber (my custom class).

Comment: It's still not clear what specifically your problem is.   Data coming back *weird* is not a detailed enough explanation of the problem